# Apply an image to a depth map in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, cs6

I created a depth map based on an image of the back of a man wearing a coat. Now I want to apply an image to the depth map, giving the appearance that the image part of the jacket. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **Displacement Map** filter.

It's a bit of a detailed processes so you would probably be better served doing a Google Search for **"[Photoshop Displacement Map Tutorial](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&q=&tab=iw#safe=off&hl=en&biw=1109&bih=1389&sclient=psy-ab&q=Photoshop%20Displacement%20Map%20Filter%20Tutorial&oq=Photoshop%20Displacement%20Map%20Filter%20Tutorial&gs_l=hp.3..33i29i30l2.640.7641.0.7865.42.30.0.12.12.1.202.2069.25j4j1.30.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.GJgEgQWbd6k&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.cGE&fp=a035af9d77fe4948)".**

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! I didnt know the proper vocabulary, but this made it very easy to get what I needed.