# How to design a t shirt in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I am using photoshop to design a t shirt..

As for the photo to look like reality I have taken a picture of a t shirt which has wrinkles. Now when I keep my Image(design) on the tshirt, it is looking like that I have kept a design. But I want the design to adjust in a way that it will adjust according to the wrinkles. I have given an example having an examples which shows both the design which I want to design(downloaded)
[image]
[image]
**Note: Green Circles: shows the image adjustment according to the t shirt..**

For more information just give a comment and I will respond in seconds.....

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for (adjusting a flat layout to match something with depth) can be found in Displacement maps. [This answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/apply-an-image-to-a-depth-map-in-photoshop-cs6/17913#17913) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to put your design over the shirt and adjust the transfer mode. The one you choose will depend on the colors of both the shirt and the design, but something like overlay or lighten/darken might work nicely.

This will make the shadows come through and give you a look that is believable enough for most people. However, if you really want to simulate the real shirt, you can also use some transform options or even the liquefy effect. This is much more work and I'm not sure how good it will look.

Make sure you experiment with all the tools you can as every situation is unique and results will definitely vary from project to project.